# How can I ignore all hard coded strings inside Log in Android Studio?

Tags: android, string, suppress-warnings, hardcoded

I have been reading about ignoring hardcoded string from Log:

Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: ");

Even inside a Toast:
Toast.makeText(context,"Hardcoded text",LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Sources:
[How can I find all RELEVANT hard coded strings in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485214/how-can-i-find-all-relevant-hard-coded-strings-in-android-studio)

[Android find all hardcoded strings in code using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799211/android-find-all-hardcoded-strings-in-code-using-android-studio)

In the first source there is the best approach but somthing is not working and that is:

"adding @SuppressLint("HardcodedNonLog") to the top of the class definition"

Is there a way to ignoring these kind of hardcoded strings?

***UPDATE***

Create a Gradle task to add "//NON-NLS" to every Log, could be a good way? If the answer is yes, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

At least with Android Studio 3.0 canary 9 (not checked with previous version).

There is option like "Annotate class 'Log' as @Non_Nls"
[image]

After that will be generated file at path "$modulename/android/util/annotations.xml" with this content:

```
<root>
   <item name='android.util.Log'>
       <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls'/>
   </item>
</root>
```

With this file all strings mentioned in Log will be ignored for this module.

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoded text is not an error it is a warning which can be dealt with by pressing left alt+ Enter. When you press alt+Enter you are just defining that hardcoded string to string.xml in values folder.